# Simulating a card game. degenerate suits

Tags: optimization, combinations, mathematical-optimization

This might be a bit cryptic title but I have a very specific problem. First my current setup

Namely in my card simulator I deal 32 cards to 4 players in sets of 8. So 8 cards per player.
With the 4 standard suits (spades, harts , etc)
My current implementation cycles threw all combinations of 8 out of 32
witch gives me a large number of possibilities.
Namely the first player can have 10518300 different hands be dealt.
The second can then be dealt 735471 different hands.
The third player then 12870 different hands.
and finally the fourth can have only 1
giving me a grand total of 9.9561092e+16 different unique ways to deal a deck of 32 cards to 4 players. if the order of cards doesn’t matter.

On a 4 Ghz processor even with 1 tick per possibility it would take me half a year.

However I would like to simplify this dealing of cards by making the exchange of diamonds, harts and spades. Meaning that dealing of 8 harts to player 1 is equivalent to dealing 8 spades. (note that this doesn’t apply to clubs)

I am looking for a way to generate this. Because this will cut down the possibilities of the first hand by at least a factor of 6. My current implementation is in c++.
But feel free to answer in a different Languages

```cpp
/** http://stackoverflow.com/a/9331125 */
unsigned cjasMain::nChoosek( unsigned n, unsigned k )
{
    //assert(k < n);
    if (k > n) return 0;
    if (k * 2 > n) k = n-k;
    if (k == 0) return 1;

    int result = n;
    for( int i = 2; i <= k; ++i ) {
        result *= (n-i+1);
        result /= i;
    }
    return result;
}
/** [combination c n p x]
 * get the [x]th lexicographically ordered set of [r] elements in [n]
 * output is in [c], and should be sizeof(int)*[r]
 * http://stackoverflow.com/a/794 */
void cjasMain::Combination(int8_t* c,unsigned n,unsigned r, unsigned x){
    ++x;
    assert(x>0);
    int i,p,k = 0;
    for(i=0;i<r-1;i++){
        c[i] = (i != 0) ? c[i-1] : 0;
        do {
            c[i]++;
            p = nChoosek(n-c[i],r-(i+1));
            k = k + p;
        } while(k < x);
        k = k - p;
    }
    c[r-1] = c[r-2] + x - k;
}
/**http://stackoverflow.com/a/9430993 */
template <unsigned n,std::size_t r>
void cjasMain::Combinations()
{
    static_assert(n>=r,"error n needs to be larger then r");
    std::vector<bool> v(n);
    std::fill(v.begin() + r, v.end(), true);
    do
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        {
            if (!v[i])
            {
                COUT << (i+1) << " ";
            }
        }
        static int j=0;
        COUT <<'\t'<< j++<< "\n";
    }
    while (std::next_permutation(v.begin(), v.end()));
    return;
}
```

A requirement is that from lexicographical number I can get back the original array.
Even the slightest optimization can help my monto carol simulation I hope.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Why do you need to generate every possible combination?

Comment: Trying to determine the best possible move and also the average number of points. It is by design not a zero sum game and bonus points allow for variable points. There is a change that one of these possibilities has over 5 times the average points. Or it might not be poisble

Comment: I am not sure to understand, do you need to find the best move for one given hand, or to find the hand that allows the best possible score?

Comment: @WilQu I am under the impression you cant find one without the other.