# unity texture2d EncodeToJPG transparent black

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, jpeg, transparency

I have a texture user drawn(on a mobile device), and I want to encode that to jpg so that user could share with that but I found the tranparent part will be black in the encoded jpg:

[image]

while I want the jpg to be like this:
[image]

But I don't find any overridden method of [`texture2d.EncodeToJPG()`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Texture2D.EncodeToJPG.html) to do this.

any ideas?

### NOTE

the wing of the bird was drawn specifically to `Color.white` so it could be white in the encoded jpg.

### Approach now

I finally manage to make this work by:

```
 Color32[] pixels = text.GetPixels32();
 Color blackTransparent = Color.black;
 blackTransparent.a = 0;
 for(int i = 0;i < pixels.Length; i++)
 {
    if(pixels[i] == blackTransparent)
    {
            pixels[i] = Color.white;
     }
  }
  text.SetPixels32(pixels);
  text.Apply();
```

But this will loop through all the pixels of the texture, if someone has a better method, plz let us know.

### Problem with this approach:

we found that there will be some edge(when meeting with the black line) on the jpg using above code, maybe need some graphic processing knowledge to solve this?
[image]

### Here is How we load image to texture2d(as required by comment)

```
  Texture2D text = new Texture2D(1, 1, TextureFormat.PVRTC_RGBA4, false);
  byte[] imagebytes = null;
  string path = "image/path/sample.png";
  if (System.IO.File.Exists(path))
  {
      Debug.Log(" really load file from " + path);
      imagebytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(path);
  }
  text.LoadImage(imagebytes, false);
```

Comment: You can improve that code. Do you run that code after you call `texture2d.EncodeToJPG()` or before?

Comment: @Programmer I run that code before `texture2d.EncodeToJPG()`

Comment: Ok. I will put an answer to improve that.

Comment: I noticed you modified your question to add information about a problem with your code....What's the source of the original Image?  What is the original format?

Comment: @Programmer origin image is png and you cloud find it [here](http://gamecdn.gifmiao.com/coloring/20170508/c47964f6d01486094a7ca293e63bc502.png)

Comment: I have to experiment with it and see what comes up best. Check back in time

Comment: @Programmer that's very nice of you!

Comment: It looks like you are taking screenshot of a drawing from the screen. If this is true, can you show me how `text` (Texture2D) is being initialized. That really matters.

Comment: @Programmer check the edit, I just put the way(simplified) of loading image there

Comment: Check my answer. Wasn't on my working machine by the time of this post yesterday.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your first question edit that asked how improve that code that is looping through all the pixels, you can. Just replace `for(int i = 0;i < pixels.Length; i++)` with `for (int i = 0; i < pixels.Length; i += 4)` then access each index from `i+0` to `i+3` inside the loop. The loop is about **4x** faster.

```
Color32[] pixels = text.GetPixels32();
Color blackTransparent = Color.black;
Color overwriteColor = Color.white;

blackTransparent.a = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < pixels.Length; i += 4)
{
    if (pixels[i] == blackTransparent)
        pixels[i] = overwriteColor;


    if (pixels[i + 1] == blackTransparent)
        pixels[i + 1] = overwriteColor;


    if (pixels[i + 2] == blackTransparent)
        pixels[i + 2] = overwriteColor;


    if (pixels[i + 3] == blackTransparent)
        pixels[i + 3] = overwriteColor;
}
text.SetPixels32(pixels);
text.Apply(true);
```

Although, both code will run into the-same jagged line problem like mentioned in your second edit.

[image]

---

---

To fix it, don't compare the pixels directly with the `==` sign. Use a function that let's you use a threshold to compare color not just the numbers. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2103368/color-logic-algorithm/2103422#2103422) is the function I use to compare RGB colors in Unity and I suggest you start using it.

You then have to manually check if the alpha is below or equals to certain value. The value of `90` seems to working great for this.

This is what the script looks like:

```
Color32[] pixels = text.GetPixels32();
Color blackTransparent = Color.black;

for (int i = 0; i < pixels.Length; i += 4)
{
    checkPixel(ref pixels[i], blackTransparent, Color.white, 600);
    checkPixel(ref pixels[i + 1], blackTransparent, Color.white, 600);
    checkPixel(ref pixels[i + 2], blackTransparent, Color.white, 600);
    checkPixel(ref pixels[i + 3], blackTransparent, Color.white, 600);
}
text.SetPixels32(pixels);
text.Apply();
```

The functions `checkPixel` and `ColourDistance` functions:

```
void checkPixel(ref Color32 pixel1, Color32 pixel2, Color32 newColor, int threshold)
{
    if (ColourDistance(pixel1, pixel2) <= threshold)
    {
        if (pixel1.a <= 90)
        {
            pixel1 = Color.white;
        }
    }
}

private static double ColourDistance(Color32 c1, Color32 c2)
{
    double rmean = (c1.r + c2.r) / 2;

    int r = c1.r - c2.r;
    int g = c1.g - c2.g;
    int b = c1.b - c2.b;
    double weightR = 2 + rmean / 256;
    double weightG = 4.0;
    double weightB = 2 + (255 - rmean) / 256;
    return Math.Sqrt(weightR * r * r + weightG * g * g + weightB * b * b);
}
```

And this is the result:

[image]

It can still be improved.

Comment: Accept as an answer before trying that :D. thank you very much for your effort.

Comment: Lol no problem but let me know if there is one.

Comment: But could you give a hint why the loop you give is *4X* times faster than the origin one I give? It seems that it has compared 4 times in one loop circle.

Comment: It is on the first line of the answer. Instead of doing `for(int i = 0;i < pixels.Length; i++)`, it is doing `for (int i = 0; i < pixels.Length; i += 4)`. Hint `i += 4` instead of `i++`.

Comment: This allows it to skip every 4 index in the pixel. It compensates those missing 4 index loops by doing `i+0`, `i+1`, `i+2` and `i+3` instead the `for` loop.  Note that `i+0` is not necessary as that will accomplish nothing. It can also be just `i`. A tricky way to loop over pixels in graphics stuff. This can also be improved by using pointers or C++.

Comment: with respect, do you mean it's the `for` loop **itself** that contributes the massive performance consuming rather that the comparison of the color? And shall we use `40` instead of `4` to get a **40X** times faster advantage? :D

Comment: Your original loop would loop `pixels.Length` times. That number is (`1,048576`) with your image on my side. If you modify it with the loop I have, it will loop `pixels.Length/4` times. That number (`262,144`). Loop can slow down image processing a-lot if it is big. Why I used 4 is because there are r,g,b,a. I don't think you can use 40 because you will have to to add 40 codes instead of 4 for each missing loop. I don't even know if you can do this without getting the exception. Try it and let me know but your code will get large.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to encode into PNG. JPG can't render transparency.

Just like :

```
texture2d.EncodeToPNG();
```

[Find complete doc here](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Texture2D.EncodeToPNG.html)

if app run on Microsoft OS you can also use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6513633/convert-transparent-png-to-jpg-with-non-black-background-color) to convert into jpg

Comment: Hi, thanks for answer the third part sharing SDK only accept a jpg file

Comment: so use this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6513633/convert-transparent-png-to-jpg-with-non-black-background-color

Comment: in c# you can do what you want

Comment: thanks, thanks, you should put the link in your answer, I will try that

Comment: If you use that, there will be no point of using Unity since the API used on that site won't work on mobile devices. I will only work on Windows.

Comment: @UnrillazTi'bob yes, it's an unity project aimed at  mobile devices.

Comment: Oh... Unity use C# and JS ? I don't know very well unity...
May be you can find something in JS ?

Comment: we are using c# with unity, not a fan of JS though :D

Comment: Try the solution above. This may work on mobile because I'm not sure that this part of code uses .NET Framework

Comment: It won't work on other devices other than Windows. Unity did not implement any .Net Image or Form stuff.