# finding "distance" between two pixel's colors

Tags: c++

Once more something relatively simple, but confused as to what they want.

the method to find distance on cartesian coordinate system is 
distance=sqrt[(x2-x1)^2 + (y2-y1)^2]

but how do i apply it here?

```
    //Requires: testColor to be a valid Color
    //Effects: returns the "distance" between the current Pixel's color and  
    //         the passed color
    //         uses the standard method to calculate "distance"
    //         uses the same formula as finding distance on a
    //         Cartesian coordinate system
    double colorDistance(Color testColor) const;
```

The color class has defined colors:
int red,green,blue

Do i define something like 'oldGreen' 'oldRed' 'oldBlue' and get the distance that way? The passed color being red,green,blue ?

http://pastebin.com/v9K30dc7

Comment: What is `Color`? Is it a struct? A class? There's no standard C++ `Color` class -- we're going to need some more code.

Comment: the very idea of distance is one that can be generalised to the ideas of a metric. (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_%28mathematics%29) What is interesting to note is  that all norms on finite dimensional vector spaces (like the Color RGB space  fore example) are equivalent up to a constant.

Comment: @Billy ONeal: yes, Color is a class. I am not sure how to work with this as the pixels color is an int...testColor  isn't ?

Comment: Then you need to show us at least the declaration, and hopefully the definition, for the class. We can't magically determine what fields/methods are inside that class.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Followup: Finding an accurate "distance" between colors](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1313/followup-finding-an-accurate-distance-between-colors)

Answer (score 7):

I'm guessing they want you to use:

```
distance = sqrt[(r2-r1)^2 + (g2-g1)^2 + (b2-b1)^2]
```

Comment: Where r, g, and b stand for red green and blue :)

Comment: Agreed - check out http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance for the more general definition

Answer (score 2):

break the color into it's red green and blue components, and use the same method, ie sqrt(sqr(delta red)+sqr(delta blue)+sqr(delta green))

note, this is not a really great method, as it doesn't allow for gamma or even the more complicated case of human perception. read http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_difference for more exotic methods.

Comment: good to know. in this case, they have us pretty limited, only using red,green,blue

Comment: That's not a fundamental problem: you can convert RGB to CIELAB, and then calculate the distance using the distance formula on Wikipedia. The RGB to CIELAB conversion is also on Wikipedia.