# Best way to compare two colors in I1I2I3 color space

Tags: colors, rgb, color-space, euclidean-distance

I'm wondering what's the proper way to compare two colors represented in [I1I2I3](http://www.couleur.org/index.php?page=transformations#I1I2I3) color space.

There are several questions about RGB similarity here on Stack ([Color similarity/distance in RGBA color space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4754506/color-similarity-distance-in-rgba-color-space), [Algorithm to check similarity of colors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5392061/algorithm-to-check-similarity-of-colors-based-on-rgb-values-or-maybe-hsv)), and one could choose some distance metrics that give fairer results compared to the classic Euclidean distance.

What's the situation with I1I2I3 color space? Is there something more accurate than Euclide's?