# Calculate how humans perceive similarity between different colours

Tags: algorithm, .net-4.0, colors, comparison

I'm working on a site where users can describe a physical object using (amongst many other things) any color in the rgb 0-255 range. We offer some simplified palettes for easy clicking but a full color wheel is a requirement.

Behind the scenes, one of the processes compares two user descriptions of the object and scores them for similarity.

What I'm trying to do is get a score for how similar the 2 colors are *in terms of human perception* . Basically, the algorithm needs to determine if a 2 humans picking 2 different colors could be describing the same object. Thus Light Red->Red should be 100%, Most of the shades of grey will be 100% to each other, etc but red-> green is definitely not a match.

To get a decent look at how the algorithms were working, I plotted grayscale and 3 intensities of each hue against every other color in the set and indicated no match (0%) with black, visually identical (100%) with white and grayscale to indicate the intermediate values.

My first (very simplistic approach) was to simply treat the RGB values as co-ordinates in the colour cube and work out the distance (magnitude of the vector) between them.

This threw out a number of problems with regards to Black->50% Grey being a larger distance than (say) Black->50% Blue. having run hundreds of comparisons and asked for feedback, this doesn't seem to match human perception (shown below)

[image: Method 1]

Method 2 converted the RGB values into [HSV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV). I then generated a score based 80% on hue with the other 20% on Sat/Lum. This seems to be the best method so far but still throws some odd matches

[image: Method 2]

Method 3 was an attempt at a hybrid - HSL Values were calculated but the final score was based upon the distance between the 2 colors in the HSL color cylinder space (as in 3D polar co-ordinates).

[image: Method 3]

I feel like I must be re-inventing the wheel - surely this has been done before? I can't find any decent examples on Google and as you can see my approach leaves something to be desired.

So, my question is:

Is there a standard way to do this? If so, how? If not, can anyone suggest a way to improve my approach? I can provide code snippets if required but be warned it's currently messy as hell due to 3 days of tweaking.

**Solution (Delta E 2000):**
Using the suggestions provided below, I've implemented a `Delta E 2000` comparer. I've had to tweak the weighting values to be quite large - I'm not looking for colors which are imperceptibly different but which are not hugely different. In case anyone's interested, the resulting plot is below...

[image: DeltaE2000]

Comment: The colors that you are comparing - do they come from images, or do the users look at images and choose representative colors? It's not clear to me if you're comparing thousands/millions of pixel values, or a handful of user-selected colors...

Comment: I'm comparing a color picked by 2 users to represent a physical object that both have seen (one of them has the object in front of them, one of them has seen it previously). The charts above were so I could get a little insight into the algorithm output so I took a range of colours and compared each colour with every other value in the range and plotted the result.

Comment: To clarify: Actually, the system allows each user to pick multiple colors if they feel it is required but the same algorithm is used to compare all color combinations and the best set of exclusive matches is taken when calculating a final score - which I believe is a level of complexity beyond what is required to understand the problem but may be interesting :)

Comment: Yeah that one is a bit more complex! http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matching_(graph_theory)#Maximum_matchings_in_bipartite_graphs

Comment: Extremely useful post! Thanks for the solution - is there a github repo for the code ?

Comment: Sorry, no. This was for something proprietary. That said, the site linked in the accepted answer has sample code and converting it was trivial, so it shouldn't be much work. Just make sure you pick the Delta E 2000 page. As to plotting the images, it was just a case of selecting a range of colours to test and plotting the similarity as grayscale on an image

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a half dozen or so possibilities. [EasyRGB](http://www.easyrgb.com/index.php?X=DELT&H=06#text6) has a page devoted to them. Of those listed, DeltaE 2000 probably has the best correlation with human perception -- and is also extremely complex to compute. Delta CMC is *almost* as good for something like half the code (though the computation still isn't entirely trivial).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, that looks very promising. As I'm very new to working with colors in this way, can you explain the meaning of the delta letters for the comparisons (E, C, H, CMC) Are these industry-wide standards?

Comment: @Basiclife: yes, they're fairly standard and well known -- if you document (for example) that you're using Delta E 2000, most people won't know the details of the calculation, but they'll know what it's for.

Comment: thanks. I'll have a look at implementing it and get back to you

Comment: I implemented Delta E 2K and it seems to be doing what I need. Thank for your help. In case you're interested, I've attached the resulting plot to the question

Comment: @Basiclife: cool -- looks pretty good -- quite a nice plot too.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% clear on how your problem is set up, but you may want to read up on: [Normalized Cross Correlation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-correlation#Normalized_cross-correlation), and [Lab](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lab_color_space) and [CIEXYZ](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CIE_XYZ_color_space) color spaces.

Comment: Thanks, I'll do the reading but to clarify: 2 users pick a color from a color wheel to describe a real-life object. I need to decide if the 2 non-identical colors should be considered "Close enough to be an exact match", "Not a match" or "Not close enough to be considered an exact match but is at least vaguely similar" (ideally as a %age). Is that any clearer?

Comment: Right, well there's probably no "standard" solution, and it might just come down to experimenting with different color spaces. Consider also incorporating training data and learning what the acceptable distance might be.

Comment: I'd come to a similar conclusion - The ideal approach would be to train the system using hundreds of human-generated comparison data points. Unfortunately, in this scenario, I don't have the time/resources to do enough training to get a decent data set.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a prime example for a neural net based approach (if you are in an experimenting mode :) because it's about creating a decision rule that mimics Human perception. A neural net that has six inputs (r, r', g, g', b, b') and one output (is_similar) can be easily trained by using e.g. your own perception of similarity as the training source!

Comment: Interesting approach - I've played with NNs before when trying to do some image matching (find me n image that looks similar to this...) and had moderate success. I hadn't considered using a NN in thi scenario but it may well be a winner. I'll dig out the old code, dust it off and have a go - Thanks for a great suggestion

Comment: There are also ready-made multi-layer perceptrons, e.g. http://neuroph.sourceforge.net/

Comment: In the end, implementing the Delta E 2000 suggestion made by Jerry was quicker but I intend to try a NN when I get the chance for comparison. Thanks again for your help