# Nice fade from red to green?

Tags: jquery, animation, colors

I am currently trying to fade a div's background directly from red to green. But I cannot find a nice transition that does not hit any non-matching colors on the way.
Both methods I found are using the jQuery.Color-plugin and you can find them also on [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sZeRU/5/):

```
 $("#rgb")
    .css("background-color", "#ff0000")
    .animate({backgroundColor: "#00ff00"});
$("#hsl")
    .css("background-color", $.Color({ hue: 0, saturation: 1, lightness: 0.5 }))
    .animate({backgroundColor: $.Color({ hue: 120, saturation: 1, lightness: 0.5 })});
```

1. The first one uses RGB. jQuery just interpolates between #ff0000 (red) and #00ff00 (green). But somewhere in the middle of the animation, the color hits rather dark yellow or brown which disturbs the impression of the whole animation (probably #888800).
2. The second one uses [HSL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV)
   But here, the animation passes via a bright yellow, since the hue-value is animated from 0 to 120, passing yellow at 60:

[image: As you can see in this image]

Is there any other way to get from red to green with a nice transition? Perhaps in theory?

Comment: Have you considered making it a 2-step transition - say, `ff0000` -> `b0b000` -> `00ff00`? This should allow you to make the "muddy" colour lighter. You might also consider adding a hint of blue to lighten it overall... It's worth noting that between Red/Green there will always be _some_ shade of yellow, be it so light it's almost white, so dark it's almost black or something in the middle...

Comment: This does indded help a little: http://jsfiddle.net/9RUBR/2/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It did only take four years to stumble upon the answer on youtube: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LKnqECcg6Gw

It has to do with the way, color is stored. As you all know, an rgb-value of (0,0,0) is black (0% photons), while (255, 255, 255) is white (100% photons). But how many photons is (127, 127, 127)?

It's not 50%, but merely about 25%. This is, what the display does when converting rgb-values to light.

Thus, when animating (255, 0, 0) to (0, 255, 0) (33% photons each) in a linear manner, it passes through (127, 127, 0) with only 25% * 1/3 + 25% * 1/3 = 16% photons, which is much darker. That's the brownish color in between.

Instead, what you should do is square the values before taking the average and take the square-root of the result afterwards.

The result is much better, since the middle-value is now (180, 180, 0) and thus much brighter.

You can play around with the value for gamma on jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/fxftm4ub/1/

```
PS: I don't know, why I got the error-message that I need to indent some code. But adding this line helped.
```

Answer (score 2):

I took the suggestion I made in the comment a little further... http://jsfiddle.net/9RUBR/3/ so we transition through `b0b080` which doesn't look bad. Or even further so it almost goes via white... http://jsfiddle.net/9RUBR/4/ - `ffffc0`

By adding slightly more blue, the transition color is closer to grey than muddy yellow. It's still not perfect but...

Incidentally, this might be a more complex problem than you initially thought. Human perception of color is very non-linear. I once had to write an algorithm which determined how similar two arbitrary colours were to a human ([Question with pretty colour plots](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5774152/156755)). The best solution I could find involved [DeltaE 2000](http://www.easyrgb.com/index.php?X=DELT&H=05#text5) (The 4th plot in the linked question)

As you can see it's quite a complex relationship between actual color and perceived color. In theory, you'd need to find the path between 2 colours (on one of those grid squares) with the smallest change in greyscale.

Answer (score 1):

did you try to put a red div on top of a green div and fade the red div out?
Maybe not the most elegent way but it should work.

Comment: Not before your answer. I did it now an this does just an rgb-transition: http://jsfiddle.net/bU4hM/