# RGB - exclude colors from certain spectrum

Tags: python, rgb

I would like to randomly generate text color and render it onto white background.
The problem is, many random generated colors are not contrasting well with white.

Currently I just use this:

```
r = lambda: random.randint(0, 255)
color = Color((r(),r(),r()))
```

Is there any library/algo out there that could eliminate certain RGB ranges to avoid blending colors, or alternatively; to compare 2 RGB colors and determine if they are in contrast or not.

Comment: What code have you tried?

Comment: So you have code to make one color, not even two, and you've made no attempt to compare them or find if there are algorithms that define good contrast (hint: there are, they are well known and very simple), or tried to make your own, and how to write them in Python.

Comment: I don't know Python. Or anything about colors. Can you give me a nudge in right direction?

Comment: Humans perceive colours in a particularly inconsistent manner (see and [old Q of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5774152/calculate-how-humans-perceive-similarity-between-different-colours)). If you want to do this rigorously, you'll need to implement DeltaE2K. For a simpler approach, look at the alternatives I tried eg RGB cubespace distance > some minimum value

Comment: @JanNetherdrake If you don't know python, then the first step is to learn Python, then as a very targeted question about a problem you have. Not just ask people to do it for you.

Comment: @LegoStormtroopr at least they show some code which probably works, which is better than a lot of newbie questions you see here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get good contrast with white, at least one of your R,G,B colors should be on the dark side. I'd choose something less than 128 just off the top of my head. Here's what I'd do:

```
from random import randint, shuffle
color = [randint(0, 255), randint(0, 192), randint(0, 128)]
shuffle(color)
color = Color(tuple(color))
```

[image: random colors]

The first line imports the functions you need from the `random` package into your namespace so they're easily accessible, without using the `package.name` idiom.

The second line generates a list of 3 random numbers. The first one covers the entire 0-255 range, the second is a little darker, and the third covers the 0-128 range that I recommended.

The third line shuffles the 3 values in-place so that the darker primary color isn't always the blue one.

The fourth line converts the list into a color you can use. Since your example showed a `Color` class that takes a tuple, I assumed you needed to convert the list into a tuple first.

Comment: This hack will do. Thanks.

Comment: -1 If you are going to write code for someone who by their own admission doesn't know the language, at least explain how it works.

Comment: @LegoStormtroopr I added a line-by-line explanation, I hope it's acceptable.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of generating the colors with RGB components, you can also generate them in a way that allows you to more directly control their intensity: you can generate the colors with **Hue Saturation Value** components ([the value controls the intensity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV)).

For example, for your white background, you can keep all the hues, but constrain the value to some range.

If you need RGB colors, at the end, you can use Python's [standard colorsys module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/colorsys.html) in order to convert HSV to RGB.

Comment: I was thinking of making a similar point, although I think the [L*a*b* color space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lab_color_space) might be a better choice in this application. Unfortunately it's not supported by `colorsys`.