# What is the most efficient way to find the euclidean distance in 3d using mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, algorithm, math, euclidean-distance

I have a MySQL table with thousands of data points stored in 3 columns R, G, B. how can I find which data point is closest to a given point (a,b,c) using Euclidean distance?

I'm saving RGB values of colors separately in a table, so the values are limited to 0-255 in each column. What I'm trying to do is find the closest color match by finding the color with the smallest euclidean distance.

I could obviously run through every point in the table to calculate the distance but that wouldn't be efficient enough to scale. Any ideas?

Comment: If you are in fact talking about **colors**, you [should probably not be using Euclidean distance in RGB space](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1313/followup-finding-an-accurate-distance-between-colors)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Since you're looking for the minimum distance and not exact distance you can skip the square root. I think [Squared Euclidean Distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance#Squared_Euclidean_Distance) applies here.
2. You've said the values are bounded between 0-255, so you can make an indexed look up table with 255 values.

Here is what I'm thinking in terms of SQL. `r0`, `g0`, and `b0` represent the target color. The table `Vector` would hold the square values mentioned above in #2. This solution would visit all the records but the result set can be set to 1 by sorting and selecting only the first row.

```
select 
    c.r, c.g, c.b,
    mR.dist + mG.dist + mB.dist as squared_dist
from 
    colors c,
    vector mR,
    vector mG,
    vector mB
where
    c.r-r0 = mR.point and
    c.g-g0 = mG.point and
    c.b-b0 = mB.point
group by
    c.r, c.g, c.b
```

Comment: I must say, that I think your solution is incorrect, user845279... If you add the 3 values, then you would find, due to the commutative laws of math (of the plus/addition), that 10 + 50 + 80 = 140, but so is 10 + 120 + 10, and so is also 1 + 138 + 1, or, 80 + 50 + 10. If you at least use the distance formula with the square root of the sum of the components each squared, then you will get a better formula for distance in the 3-dimensional space comprising of the X-Y-Z cube (R-G-B) ranging for each dimension between 0 to 255...

Answer (score 3):

I think the above comments are all true, but they are - in my humble opinion - not answering the original question. (Correct me if I'm wrong). So, let me here add my 50 cents:

You are asking for a select statement, which, given your table is called 'colors', and given your columns are called r, g and b, they are integers ranged 0..255, and you are looking for the value, in your table, closest to a given value, lets say: rr, gg, bb, then I would dare trying the following:

```
select min(sqrt((rr-r)*(rr-r)+(gg-g)*(gg-g)+(bb-b)*(bb-b))) from colors;
```

Now, this answer is given with a lot of caveats, as I am not sure I got your question right, so pls confirm if it's right, or correct me so that I can be of assistance.

Comment: Hm? Huh? I was putting some stars to multiply, instead of becoming stars, (asterisk), it made the code italic, ha ha ha... So, between the parenthesis of (rr-r)(rr-r) there was supposed to be a star. Likewise with (gg-g)(gg-g), ha ha ha... THis is a formatting style used since latex in the 1980's on mainframes !!! (yeah, I'm an old chap)...

Comment: thanks for answering the question in SQL which is what I was trying to do - although I wonder if this would be horribly efficient

Answer (score 2):

The first level of optimization that I see you can do would be square the distance to which you want to limit the query so that you don't need to perform the square root for each row. 
The second level of optimization I would encourage would be some preprocessing to alleviate the need for extraneous squaring for each query (which could possibly create some extra run time for large tables of RGB's). You'd have to do some benchmarking to see, but by substituting in values for a, b, c, and d and then performing the query, you could alleviate some stress from MySQL.

[image: Latex]

Note that the performance difference between the last two lines may be negligible. You'll have to use test queries on your system to determine which is faster.

I just re-read and noticed that you are ordering by distance. In which case, the d should be removed everything should be moved to one side. You can still plug in the constants to prevent extra processing on MySQL's end.

Answer (score 0):

I believe there are two options.

You have to either as you say iterate across the entire set and compare and check against a maximum that you set initially at an impossibly low number like -1.  This runs in linear time, n times (since you're only comparing 1 point to every point in the set, this scales in a linear way).

I'm still thinking of another option... something along the lines of doing a breadth first search away from the input point until a point is found in the set at the searched point, but this requires a bit more thought (I imagine the 3D space would have to be pretty heavily populated for this to be more efficient on average though).

Answer (score 0):

If you run through every point and calculate the distance, don't use the square root function, it isn't necessary. The smallest sum of squares will be enough.

This is the [problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closest_pair_of_points_problem) you are trying to solve. (Planar case, select all points sorted by a x, y, or z axis. Then use PHP to process them)

MySQL also has a [Spatial Database](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/spatial-extensions.html) which may have this as a function. I'm not positive though.

Comment: I was looking at that wikipedia page on the closest pair of points problem too, but that is for comparing all points to all other points to find the minimum distance between each pair. Not to mention I believe you would need to sort based on two of the three dimensions and the sorting would hurt efficiency.  Also it seems the Spatial Database only deals with 2 dimensional points though I haven't used it.