# Algorithm to map Numbers to Hex Colors

Tags: algorithm, colors, hex

Here's my situation.  Say I have two columns of data containing different elements.  I'd like to highlight with a different color, all matching elements between those two columns.  Each of those elements has an ID, so I was thinking of creating a mapping function to tie an ID to a hex color.  Any suggestions?

This is what I was thinking: Add an arbitrary number, say 111, to each hex number to generate the new color (and mod it take care of overflow)... so 111*id + Starting hex number.

Is this reasonable? Does anyone have a suggestion for the *111* so that the colors are diverse early on, but don't mod to the same value that quickly?  Say I'd like 50 unique colors, as diverse as possible.

Thanks,
Michael

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/180/function-for-creating-color-wheels This will be of help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While the HSV colour space is probably better in terms of giving you "different-looking" colours, RGB is probably "good enough".

You could just let Red, Green and Blue be one of {0, 40, 7F, FF}. This gives 4x4x4 = 64 colours. Something like this:

```
Red = ID % 4
Grn = (ID / 4) % 4
Blu = (ID / 16) % 4

print hex(floor(Red * 255 / 3)) //etc
```

The human eye is supposed to detect changes in Green more readily than Red/Blue. So if you need some more colours you can let Red and Blue take on 4 possible values and Green take on 5 (giving 80 colours).

If you don't want consecutive IDs to be *too* close together in colour you can create an array that maps IDs to a shuffled set of numbers.

Also if your IDs aren't all nicely consecutive from 0 to 63 then you could make your program find all the IDs that are actually *used* and map them to numbers between 0 and 63.