# What is the Algorithm behind a color wheel?

Tags: objective-c, colors

I would like to draw a color wheel on my iPhone Application, how can I do so?

What is the Algorithm behind the color wheel? Thank you.

[image: http://realcolorwheel.com/colorwheel.htg/RCW600x600.png]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Math behind the Colour Wheel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4235072/math-behind-the-colour-wheel)

Answer (score 2):

If you are familiar with HSA color system the algorithm will be simple.

A color wheel depicts Hue and Saturation. The hue varies with the angle, and the saturation varies with the radius. For more information you can take a look at http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/4235072/math-behind-the-colour-wheel