# How to implement the color wheel inside the UIView?

Tags: objective-c, colors, quartz-graphics

I searched the web site, and I found how to draw a color wheel...
[Math behind the Colour Wheel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4235072/math-behind-the-colour-wheel)

But I would like to implement it by drawing on the UIView. But how can I do using the Quartz technology? I should draw from by dots or lines? Thank you

Comment: Just to clarify, are you asking how to actually draw a color wheel itself?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe its use for you.

1. CGContext*** functions to draw dots or lines, and UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext to get UIImage item.

-(void) drawPoint:(CGPoint)point {
    CGContextBeginPath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
    CGContextMoveToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), point.x, point.y);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), point.x, point.y);
    CGContextStrokePath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
}

-(void) drawLineFrom:(CGPoint)start
                  to:(CGPoint)end {
    CGContextBeginPath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
    CGContextMoveToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), start.x, start.y);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), end.x, end.y);
    CGContextStrokePath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
}

1. Draw UIImage to UIView.
   UIColor* backColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:your_image_from_cgcontext];
   view.backgroundColor = backColor;